# Having trouble with this generic struct with an async fn that produces a Stream

Tags: rust

As you can discern from the title, there are quite a few concepts colliding in this example:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=054bd4a02fe6eb72e50b6843ba04449d

What I'm trying to do:

- I have a generic async function that produces some result `T` and takes a simple `i32` param (a page number)
- Struct `Pager` holds this async `fetch` function
- `Pager`'s `stream` fn produces a `Stream` over the `T`s returned from the `fetch` function using `stream::unfold` and incrementing the page number.

My efforts to get this to work have been frustrating. I think that's because I'm only a month into learning Rust and solving this problem requires using generics, async/await, closures, and a few other concepts all at once. I feel like I'm close but I admit that I'm pretty stuck. The current error has to do with lifetimes and I'm at a loss to decipher it:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
```

I have two questions:

1. Am I going about this the right way? Is there anything about this example structurally that can be simplified? I'm working backwards from the way I wan to use this code (as in the `main` fn of the playground: create a Pager where I need one to wrap a fetch function).
2. How can I get past this error (and whatever error comes next) to get this stripped down example working?

Thanks for reading this far and for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is trying (somewhat cryptically) to tell you that it cannot be certain the `Pager` instance will not have been dropped by the time that `self.fetch` is invoked.

Indeed, since you are asserting that the `Stream` should have `'static` lifetime, the compiler is trying to ensure it's safe to call `self.fetch` *at any time* thereafter—which will include after the `Pager` *has* been dropped (whenever that be).  But once dropped, `self.fetch` (the location where the pointer to the fetch function can be found) will have been deallocated and you are attempting use-after-free.

So, what's the solution?  There are two options:

1. Assert that the `Pager` instance outlives the `Stream`:

   ```
   fn stream<'a>(&'a self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = T> + 'a>> { ... }
   ```

   If you adopt this approach, then you must consider that the closure argument to `unfold` captures `&'a self` from its environment.  By default, it does this by *borrowing* the `&'a self`—leaving you with `&&'a self` inside the closure (where the outer borrow lives for the remainder of the `stream` function call); again, this is not long enough—you need a borrow that lasts for the lifetime of the `Stream`, which `move` can give you by moving the `&'a self` into the closure:

   ```
   stream::unfold(0, move |state| ...);
   ```

   Furthermore, the `async` block within the closure *also* captures its environment—again borrowing by default, which entails the same issue as with the closure.  So you need to `move` the `&'a self` now from the closure into the `async` block:

   ```
   async move { ... }
   ```

   (You were already doing this).

   Giving us overall:

   ```
   fn stream<'a>(&'a self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = T> + 'a>> {
       let stream = stream::unfold(0, move |state| async move {
           let yielded = (self.fetch)(state).await;
           let next_state = state + 1;
           Some((yielded, next_state))
       });
       Box::pin(stream)
   }
   ```

   See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=74ac1109a9376ff78f0a36fdc3bd94f4).
2. Alternatively, since `self.fetch` is a function pointer rather than a closure (the pointee captures no state) and `unfold` does not capture any other state from `Pager`, then if the value of `fetch` at the time `unfold` is invoked remains valid forever thereafter (even if `Pager` is dropped) you could simply copy the function pointer out of `self` so that it can be moved into the closure:

   ```
   fn stream(&self) -> Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = T>>> {
       let fetch = self.fetch;
       let stream = stream::unfold(0, move |state| async move {
           let yielded = fetch(state).await;
           let next_state = state + 1;
           Some((yielded, next_state))
       });
       Box::pin(stream)
   }
   ```

   (As before, we still need to `move` this copied function pointer into the closure and then into the `async` block, as mere borrows of the local `fetch` variable would not last long enough).

   Note that this approach requires that the `F` type parameter be constrained to the `'static` lifetime:

   ```
   F: Future<Output = T> + 'static,
   ```

   See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1be39d0dac17ee0cbb90237994095015).

Comment: Thank you for the correct (and quick) reply! I need to read more about `move`. Code like this is especially puzzling to me:

    `move |state| async move`

(I noticed you had to add that first `move`)

Comment: @recursivevirus: I've added both an explanation of `move` and also an alternative, `'static` solution.